# PHP random COM object problems on WAMP

Tags: php, com, apache2

I am using an old COM object / ActiveX-control in a PHP application. It runs under Windows/Apache. Normally everything is fine but sometimes I get

> Failed to create COM object 'TTF161.TTF1': Objektserver wird beendet, wenn der OLE-Dienst ihn aufruft.

The german part of the message means something like *Objectserver terminates when the OLE-service calls it*.

I tried enclosing the creation of the object with try-catch but it does not work.

The problem occurs randomly with the very same request. So it is not related to anything of the programming logic and I assume this old component is just a bit buggy and fails from time to time. But I would like to handle that situation like try again or give the user a better error message. I could also imagine that it is related to the number of apache threads or processes. The event log does not state anyhting and also Apache error log is empty.

I would appreciate any hint how I can handle/catch the problem or where I might find more information.

Comment: Which PHP version are you running?

Comment: English translation: "Object server is stopping when OLE service contacts it", see http://finderr.net/search

Comment: @JPW: If still interested, this happens on PHP 5.2.

Comment: According to this site http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php you should be able to catch the error. What code are you using to create the object/catch the error?

Comment: @JPW I got `set_exception_handler()`, a try-catch around the COM creation (`new COM(...)`). We are currently testing a new VM with 32bit, PHP 5.4, Apache 2.4 and I am still waiting for the results when the page is on load.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works for me (Win XP SP3, PHP 5.2.17 (cli) (built: Jan  6 2011 17:37:45)):

```
<?php
  try
  {
    echo "Trying to create object"."\r\n";
    $obj = new COM("FailingObject");
    echo "Object created";
  }
  catch(com_exception $e)
  {
    echo "Caught exception"."\r\n";
    $c = $e->getCode();
    $m = $e->getMessage();
    echo "Error Code: ".dechex($c)."\r\n";
    echo $m;
  }
?>
```

Executing this script using PHP on the command line yields the expected result:

> Trying to create object
>   Caught exception
>   Error Code: 80080008
>   Failed to create COM object `FailingObject': Object server is stopping when
>   OLE service contacts it

The tested object "FailingObject" is a simple ATL COM object which uses

```
HRESULT FinalConstruct()
{
    return CO_E_SERVER_STOPPING;
}
```

to simulate an error during object creation.

My best guess is (and I could be completely wrong with this) that in your case the error is not thrown by the object creation but by a different COM call somewhere within PHP which then is not handled correctly.

You might consider filing a bug report for this behavior because normally you should be able to catch the error.